# Problem with understanding the transformation of Hessian in primitive internal coordinates to Hessian in delocalized internals

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

I am currently working out the theory of Hessians in different coordinate systems. Using the Wilson B matrix $\mathbf{B}=B_{ij}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_j}$, where $q_i$ denotes the $i$th primitive internal coordinate and $x_j$ is the $j$th Cartesian coordinate I can form a $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{BB}^\top$. After diagonalizing $\mathbf{G}$ I obtain a matrix $\mathbf{U}$ as the set of nonredundant eigenvectors of $\mathbf{G}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda > 0$. $\mathbf{U}$ spans the nonredundant subspace of the space of primitive internals $\mathbf{q}$. I can use $\mathbf{U}$ to transform the diagonal $n\times n$ Hessian $\mathbf{H}^{\text{prim}}$ in the space of primtive internal coordinates to the space of delocalized internal coordinates using:

$\mathbf{H}^{\text{DLC}}=\mathbf{U}^\top\mathbf{H}^{\text{prim}}\mathbf{U}$.

Can somebody explain this non-linear transformation in a physical and/or mathematical sense? I don't get why I have to use $\mathbf{U}$ two times (apart from deriving the right dimensionality of $\mathbf{H}^{\text{DLC}}$).

Comment: Didn't you just explain the mathematical "sense" of it?

Comment: I suspect **U** is orthogonal and thus the last equation would be a similarity transform. Wikipedia will tell you a lot about those, and math.SE the rest.

Comment: It does look a bit like a similarity transform these have the general form in your example of $U^{-1}H^{prim}U$ where *U* are matrices of eigenvectors. In your case they seem to be orthogonal $U^T=U^{-1}$. The transform is equivalent to changing the basis set or equivalently a coordinate ('rotational')  transformation. Usually they are used to diagonalise matrices.

Comment: @Porphyrin     It indeed seems to be a similarity transform. Thank you for your anwswer.